# Setting working directory in R (Jumping directories)

Tags: r

R doesn't allow me to set the newly created folder as the working directory if I jump folders. I don't actually set working directories this way, but I am curious as to why it is exhibiting this behaviour.

First I set my working directory:

`original_directory <-setwd('C:/Users/rooirokbokkie/Documents')`

Now  I want to create two folders in my current working directory with folder_2 being a sub-folder of folder_1:

`dir.create(file.path('folder_1', 'folder_2'), recursive = TRUE)`

When I try to set folder_2 as the working directory:

`setwd('folder_2')`

I get the following error:

`Error in setwd("folder_2") : cannot change working directory`

But if I set folder_1 as the working directory first, it works:

`setwd('folder_1')`

`setwd('folder_2')`

`getwd()`

`[1] C:/Users/rooirokbokkie/Documents/folder_1/folder_2"`
`

But when I try to back up one folder it gives the error again:

`setwd('folder_1')`

`Error in setwd("folder_1") : cannot change working directory`

But I can set my original working directory again just fine:

`setwd(original_directory)`

`getwd()`

`[1] "C:/Users/rooirokbokkie/Documents"`

What gives?

Comment: Use full path specification for setting your working directory `setwd("C:/Users/rooirokbokkie/Documents/folder_1/")` and `setwd("C:/Users/rooirokbokkie/Documents/folder_1/folder_2")`

Comment: Just to elaborate on the above comment: If you do not supply absolute ("full") paths, then R interprets everything relative to its current working directory. Every error you get can be explained by this.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to specify the full path to folder_2 (as noted in comments).

The other option, since folder_2 is a subfolder of folder_1 and folder_1 is in your current working directory, you can specify a relative path but starting from your current working directory. So in order to set your working directory to folder_2 you need to specify:

```
setwd("folder_1/folder_2")
```

Now if you want to jump back and forth, you can do the following:

```
# capture the "old" working directory
old_dir <- getwd()
# set new wd to folder_2:
setwd("folder_1/folder_2")
# jump to folder_1:
setwd(paste0(old_dir, "/folder_1"))
# jump to original wd:
setwd(old_dir)
```

Comment: Problem with this is that the user wants to move back and forth between directories, as such, if you set working directory `setwd("folder_1/folder_2")` using `setwd("folder_1")` wont work again. Hoop dit help